# blackberry 7 slide menu like facebook?

Tags: blackberry

Can any one suggest me is there any open source lib for sliding menu like we have for android?

[image]

I want to achieve something like in blackberry.

OR

What are the other good options to achieve this?

I want to implement this in bb7 because in bb10 action menu is already there to achieve the same thing.

Thanks

Comment: try this sample - http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2013/09/creating-facebook-like-slider-menu-in.html

Comment: @Signare ,Thanks i will try it and once i will implement it i will accept your answer as my solution

Comment: A sliding panel is a bad idea for BB7 since most devices are non-touch and a person will have to navigate a lot to click on the button to open it. Instead capture the menu button press and pop up the actions screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the approach taken by Facebook to do the scrolling is complicated to implement and requires some detailed understanding of BlackBerry UI along with some tricky animation coding. And you will note that it is nothing like Android.  The menu items swipe over and completely replace the screen, they do NOT push the current screen to the right.  Pushing the screen partially to the right is not very BB like and will (as has been pointed out) cause difficulties on trackpad only devices.

A much simpler implementation, that I think will give similar look and feel to the Facebook implementation, is to use screen transitions.  This Is how I would approach this, and I would use three steps:

1) In your first iteration, you can just create a transparent screen, with your menu items as buttons, and push it over the top of your current screen.  There are issues creating a transparent MainScrees, because of the number of Managers hidden in a MainScreen, so use a FullScreen for this, and create a background using something like this:

```
BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(0, 0));
```

You can play with this to get it looking like what you want (for example to configure full width buttons).

2) When this is working, use screen transitions to have it slide over the top from the left - this gives you something like the Facebook menus.  Here is some screen transition doc:

[Screen transitions overview](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Screen_transitions_detailed_overview_806391_11.jsp)

3) To get it looking just like the Facebook menus, have a transparent region at the top that matches the 'header' area of your app, and then it will look like the menus are sliding in underneath the header.

It might be in fact this is what the Facebook team actually did!

Now I must be honest, I have never done this, so I can't give you code, or even guarantee this will work.  But I am confident it will and happy to help if you find any issues.

Re the code presented in here:

http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2013/09/creating-facebook-like-slider-menu-in.html

If you are considering using it, I suggest you review the variation on this code that I supplied in answer to a similar question, see:

[blackberry-why-is-this-browserfield-disappearing-from-the-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559007/blackberry-why-is-this-browserfield-disappearing-from-the-screen-after-this-ch)

**Update**

Kevin's comments below suggest another variation (thanks Kevin).

There is the possibility that you do not need to code the animation - because scrollable managers will scroll to display the focusable Field when focus changes.  So one way of moving the "drawer" is to programmatically change the focus.  This only works if you have full width focus items of course.

So it is possible that you can insert the menus into a scrollable HFM at position 0, then set focus on them, the HFM will scroll for you, then using ScrollListener, remove the right hand side when the scroll is (nearly) finished.  Reverse to scroll back.  I think I have glossed over a few implementation details, but the principle sounds reasonable.

Also following Kevin's comment, I did not appreciate that the transparent parts of a popped screen  went black, that is something I might have a play with.

Comment: Pretty much correct. I am currently working on this too, but the screen transition to overlap doesn't really work. since when you pop the drawer the transparent background becomes black.

I basically created a horizontally scrollable "activity", then add/delete the drawer from either side when the drawer needs to be opened/closed. Just to prevent the screen from scrolling or losing focus.

With some handling in scroll listener it works pretty well.